# Efficient estimators

Tags: self-study, estimation, inference, cauchy-distribution

let $x_{1},..,x_{n}$ be iid with cauchy distribution.
Let $y=median(x_{1},..,x_{n})$ , $z=MLE$. I get that $y$ is not an asymptotically efficient estimator to the location of a cauchy distribution because the asymptotic approximation to the distribution of the sample median has variance ${\pi}^2/4$ and minimum variance is $1/2$. Is $z$ asymptotically efficient estimator?

Comment: You may want to review the regularity conditions for Cramér–Rao bound properties and MLEs. Also [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2282794) contains the answer.